# How to set the where condition in Laravel using with function?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How to set the where condition in Laravel using with the function. I am beginner in Laravel.

```
public function rejectedkyc(Request $request)

{
    $sort_search = null;
    $users = User::with('account')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');

    if (!empty($request->search))
    {
        $sort_search = $request->search;
        $users->where(function ($q) use ($sort_search)
        {
            $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $sort_search . '%')->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $sort_search . '%')->orWhere('phone', 'like', '%' . $sort_search . '%')->orWhere('referral_code', 'like', '%' . $sort_search . '%')->orWhere('username', 'like', '%' . $sort_search . '%');
        });
    }
    $user_type = null;
    if (!empty($request->user_type))
    {
        $user_type = $request->user_type;
        $users->where(function ($q) use ($user_type)
        {
            $q->where('user_type', 'like', '%' . $user_type . '%');
        });
    }

    $users = $users->paginate(15);
    //dd($users);
    return view('backend.customer.customers.pending', compact('users', 'sort_search', 'user_type'));

}
```

Comment: i want to set where condition in 'account' table and 'status' column

Answer (score 0):

use [`->when()`](https://laraveldaily.com/post/less-know-way-conditional-queries)

```
$sort_search = $request->has('search') ? $request->get('search') : null;
$user_type = $request->has('user_type') ? $request->get('user_type') : null;

$users = User::with('account')
    ->when(isset($sort_search), static function ($query) use ($sort_search) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $sort_search . '%')->orWhere('email', 'like', '%' . $sort_search . '%')->orWhere('phone', 'like', '%' . $sort_search . '%')->orWhere('referral_code', 'like', '%' . $sort_search . '%')->orWhere('username', 'like', '%' . $sort_search . '%');
    })
    ->when(isset($user_type), static function ($query) use ($user_type) {
        $query->where('user_type', 'like', '%' . $user_type . '%');
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->paginate(15);

return view('backend.customer.customers.pending', compact('users', 'sort_search', 'user_type'));
```

Comment: what is this ??

Comment: @dev why are you posting random codes?